# Error nodemon (NODEJS)

Tags: base-de-datos, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer `api` creando un backend con `nodejs`. Cuando hago un `post` o un `get` desde la aplicación de **postman** me da un error en la terminal y no puedo hacer más post o get a la base de datos hasta cerrar y volver a iniciar la aplicación. El error es el siguiente:

> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
>   Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

```
    'use strict'

    var Project=require('../models/project');
    var controller={
        home:function(req,res){
            return res.status(200).send({
                message:'Soy el home'
            })
        },
        test:function(req,res){
            return res.status(200).send({
                message:'Soy el metodo test del controlador del proyecto'
            })
        },
        saveProject:function(req,res){
            var project=new Project();
            var params=req.body;
            project.name=params.name;
            project.description=params.description;
            project.category=params.category;
            project.year=params.year;
            project.image=null;

        project.save((err,projectStored)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message:'Error en la petición'});
            if(!projectStored) return res.status(404).send({message:'No se ha podido guardar el proyecto'})

            return res.status(200).send({project:projectStored});
        });


        return res.status(200).send({
            project:project,
            message:'Metodo save project'
        })
    },

    getProject:function(req,res){
        var projectID=req.params.id;
        if(projectID==null) return res.status(404).send({message:'El proyecto no existe'});

        Project.findById(projectID,(err,project)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message:'Error al devolver los datos'});
            if(!project) return res.status(404).send({message:'El proyecto no existe'})

            return res.status(200).send({project});
        })
    }
    };


    module.exports=controller;
```

Comment: Hola al parecer despues de algun `send` te falta un `return`. Pon el código del request que haces para confirmarlo por favor. Puedes editar la pregunta.

Comment: @Angel Te refieres al código del archivo del controlador supongo no? te lo edito ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sobra un `return` dentro de `saveProject:`

```
saveProject:function(req,res){
            var project=new Project();
            var params=req.body;
            project.name=params.name;
            project.description=params.description;
            project.category=params.category;
            project.year=params.year;
            project.image=null;
        // Esta operacion es asincrona y se ejecuta despues del ultimo return.
        project.save((err,projectStored)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message:'Error en la petición'});
            if(!projectStored) return res.status(404).send({message:'No se ha podido guardar el proyecto'})

            return res.status(200).send({project:projectStored});
        });
   
#AQUI TE SOBRA ESTE RETURN. Dejaselo al projec.save
        return res.status(200).send({
            project:project,
            message:'Metodo save project'
        })
    },
```

## Explicacion

Al hacer `project.save(//...)` estas creando una petición asincrona. Node espera a que esta termine para mandar la respuesta pero antes de que el `save` se cumpla (termine sus operaciones) tu ya estas mandando el siguiente `return res.estatus(200)`. Es una idea parecida a los multi-hilos, solo que en este caso el esta esperando que el `save` termine. Cuando lo termina tiene dos respuestas que no es compatible con esta arquitectura y no sabe que hacer. Por eso te retorna el error.

Aun asi, puedes poner el mensaje en el `save` y eliminar esa linea:

```
project.save((err,projectStored)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message:'Error en la petición'});
            if(!projectStored) return res.status(404).send({message:'No se ha podido guardar el proyecto'})
```

---

```
            return res.status(200).send({
                      project:projectStored, 
                      message:'Metodo save project'});
            });
```

Comment: Ha funcionado gracias. Podrías explicarme por que al subirlo al project.save funciona bien y cuando lo he intentado eliminar me ha vuelto a dar un error? porque creo que solo es un mensaje que sale y si quitase ese mensaje debería seguir funcionando pero parece que no

Comment: Pongo la respuesta.